# Weak force beta + and - decays

Tags: fusion

What is the role of the weak nuclear force in nuclear fusion, changing a proton to a neutron to produce deuterium and in neutron stars when a fundamental particle, the lepton electron, is fused in to the composite protons?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Check Wikipedia;s [The proton–proton chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain#The_proton%E2%80%93proton_chain) and add to your question at what point you are getting stuck by editing your post. At some point your question will probably be migrated to Astronomy SE. That's okay, don't worry, then you can join that site as well.

Comment: the particle you're missing is the neutrino.  a proton changes into a neutron plus an anti-electron and an electron-neutrino, and that interaction is mediated by a weak force vector boson.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ProfRob it seems to be "What is the role of the weak nuclear force in nuclear fusion when the electron is fused in to the composite protons?" I'm not saying that that's necessarily a clear and/or good question. Would something like "Protons cna beta decay to neutrons just as easily as neutrons to protons, as long as there's enough energy available - so the role is the same as it is for neutron decay, except that the electron is now a positron" be an answer perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately we may never know - the user doesn't seem to be active after posting in Space SE.